# Why does SQL throw an error when BULK INSERT is used?

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert values into the table from a csv. Here is my code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Books; 
CREATE TABLE Books (
     Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     Author VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     Pages INT
 );
 BULK INSERT Books
 FROM 'C:\Users\poreb\Desktop\Projects\Book Database\books.csv'
 WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
        FIRSTROW = 2);
SELECT * FROM Books
```

The error that I'm getting is:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BULK INSERT Books
> FROM 'C:\Users\poreb\Desktop\Projects\Book Database\books.cs' at line 1
> CONSOLERE-RUN QUERYEXPORTOPEN

In the MySQL installer, it says that the server version is 8.0.30.

Comment: There is no bulk insert in MySQL to my knowledge - do you have a reference for it?

Comment: Do not confuse MySQL and MS SQL.

Answer (score 1):

[BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is a Microsoft SQL Server command. It is not supported by MySQL.

MySQL has a similar command called [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/load-data.html). Some usage of it is different from Microsoft's BULK INSERT command, so read the documentation carefully.

Despite starting with the same syllable, Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL are entirely different products. I.e. they are developed by different companies, and are implemented with different code. They have different features. You should read the documentation for the product you use, and do not expect features from one to be supported in the other.